# Problem with reading Json file,c#,Newtonsoft.Json;

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I don't know why,but before the path it adds backslash.Works in a console app ,but doesn't work in a maui shell app
[[image]

[image]

```
namespace RakeshProj;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        JsonRead(@"C:\Users\Matsenko\source\repos\TestJson\TestJson\json.json");
    }
    public static void JsonRead(string _path)
    {
        dynamic JsoneFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(_path));
        Console.WriteLine(JsoneFile["title"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException means that application could not find a file located in provided path. Make sure that folder & file exists on your PC.

Comment: Are you running this application in a Windows environment? If you write `Environment.OSVersion.ToString()` to the console, what does it say? It looks like ```C:\``` is not recognized as the drive letter/root folder.

Comment: Look,it works in a console app,but doesn't work in maui shell app

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: dont use @. 
"C:\\Users\\Matsenko\\source\\repos\\TestJson\\TestJson\\json.json"
also, application might not have an access to users folder. make it separate like "c:\\Test\\TestJson.json"